# Image files have got changed but pictures look the same

Tags: regex, image, apache, .htaccess, server

I recently have got many files (especially image thumbnails) changed mysterily on my server. I am trying to figure out what happened.

I found a .htaccess file under my site's image folder, the image folder is in the same directory of my homepage. But I did not upload this file to the server, and did not do any configuration on cPanel that generating this file. The code is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help to interpret what the above code does? Thanks in advance.

And also, when I synchronized my local site and the remote site in Dreamweaver, there were always some images especially thumbnails changed on the server, Dreamweaver prompted "No synchronization necessary", but if I viewed the log, Dreamweaver did say "this file has been changed since last synchronization" but marked with "ignored", when I compared these changed files with local site, winmerge prompted that "the two files are identical". I assumed Dreamweaver did not really find out the changes.

However, the image files changed found by my cron job "find /MY PATH TO DIRECTORY -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -ls" did shows the difference when I compared them in winmerge (I could see the differences but could not understand those code of the image files". My question is how the image files get changed, the pictures look the same but the information containing inside the file get changed, how the change could be done and what the change could be for? Is there any security issues?

Any help would be appreciated.

Seahorse.

Comment: You should also consider asking this question on [**`serverfault.com`**](http://serverfault.com/). You can use your S.O account to auto-join over there.

Comment: Those directives tell your server to load your `index.php` if user is coming from search engine or is their crawler.

Comment: why isn't it under the same directory of my index.php but in the image folder? is it the default server setting? I did not know when it is sitting there and who put it there.